# getting babel-node to work with yarn v2/3

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a project with the following structure

```
./
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── package.json
├── .yarnrc.yml
├── packages
│   ├── pkg-1
│   │   ├── babel.config.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── pkg-2
│       ├── babel.config.js
│       ├── index.js
│       └── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

pkg-2 has a dependency on pkg-1.

pkg-1/index.js looks like this

```js
export function printName(){
  console.log('my name');
}

console.log('print name')
```

pkg-2/index.js looks like this

```js
import { printName } from "pkg-1";
printName()
```

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

pkg-2/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "pkg-2",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pkg-1": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10"
  }
}
```

running the command `yarn workspace pkg-1 run start` prints `print name` as expected. However, running `yarn workspace pkg-2 run start` results in the following

```
/Users/mds31/Documents/testing/yarn/packages/pkg-1/index.js:1
export function printName(){
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Module._compile (/Users/mds31/Documents/testing/yarn/.yarn/cache/pirates-npm-4.0.5-22f8e827ce-c9994e61b8.zip/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:136:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at require$$0.Module._extensions..js (/Users/mds31/Documents/testing/yarn/.pnp.cjs:13055:33)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/mds31/Documents/testing/yarn/.yarn/cache/pirates-npm-4.0.5-22f8e827ce-c9994e61b8.zip/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:141:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.require$$0.Module._load (/Users/mds31/Documents/testing/yarn/.pnp.cjs:12895:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

presumably this is cos pkg-1 is not being compiled, is there a config setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround to this that involves building all the packages before running with `yarn node`. This is made a bit easier with this tool https://yarn.build/ which will run the build command of all workspaces.

script for running now looks like

```json
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel index.js --out-dir dist",
    "start": "yarn build && yarn node dist/index.js"
  }
}
```